# Firebase custom parameters can use with adwords or any google ads?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, ads, facebook-analytics

I have a question about Firebase that if I use custom parameters in event tracking. It will has effect to using Adwords or any **Google Ads** or not ??

Because **Facebook Ads**, it also has custom parameters in event tracking but custom parameters can't use with some **Facebook Ads**. it is available only for **predefined parameter only**.

So, I would like to know custom parameters in Firebase. It has effect to some **Google Ads** or not ??

**Thank you so much :)**

Comment: I'm an engineer on Facebook Analytics. I know your question is about Google Ads, but you mentioned in your comment that Facebook Ads only support targeting based on predefined parameters. You actually can use custom parameters for Facebook Ads. You can create an event filter in Facebook Analytics (see: [[link](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/312042699185458)]) and then add a refinement by custom parameter value, and then use this filter to create a custom audience (see: [[link](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/873248312763139)].)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mark any events (custom/standard/standard SDK) as a conversion and use it in Google Ads app campaigns.